# Docker inside docker : volume is mounted, but empty

Tags: docker, dockerpy

I am running a docker container with docker mounted inside using :

```
docker run -v /Path/to/service:/src/service -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock --net=host image-name python run.py
```

This runs a python script that creates a `data` folder in `/src` and fills it. When printing `os.listdir('/src/data')`, I get a list of files.

I then run a container from within this container, mounting the `data` folder, using `docker-py`.

```
volumes = {'/src/data': {'bind': '/src', 'mode': 'rw'}}    
client.containers.run(image, command='ls data', name=container_key, network='host', volumes=volumes)
```

And it prints :

```
Starting with UID: 0 and HOME: /src\n0\n'
```

Which means `data` is mounted, but empty. What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So- mounting docker inside the container means that containers started from in there are running on your HOST machine.

The end result is you have two containers on host- one with
`/Path/to/service:/src/service`
and one with
`/src/data:/src`

If you want to share a volume between two containers you should usually use a "named" volume like
`docker run -v sharedvolume:/src/data` and `docker run -v sharedvolume:/src`

Comment: This saved my day. Thank you very much . Thanks to OP as well for asking this question